# Cosmosdb index precision for fixed value strings

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb

I want to index over a field in a collection whose values can be only 4 characters long

`{ "field": "abcd" }`

Can I use an index precision of 4 like below to save on RU's without having any side effects?

`"indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": 4
                }, 
            ]`

Answer (score 1):

For Range indexes, the index term length will never exceed the actual string length. So,if all of your strings are 4 characters long, then this will not have any impact (neither positive or negative). You're better off, however, to set the precision to -1 so that we don't have to change your index policy in the future in case the length of the strings changes.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Out of curiosity, will we have considerable savings in terms of RUs if we used smaller precision to save indices? Can you just give some figures?

Comment: I am from the CosmosDB engineering team. The precision of the term does not have an impact on the RU cost per term. Roughly the RU cost corresponds to cost of writing the document (which depends on the size of the document) and the number of terms produced during analysis of the document. If you want to reduce the RU cost of your writes, you should exclude all paths that you don't need to index from your indexing policy.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [official statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-types#index-precision), the choice of the index precision might affect the performance of string range queries. Obviously, there is no specific statements about 
effect like hash type index. So,I suggest you do actual test based on the simulation data instead so that maybe you could find the truth.

BTW, if you want to perform `ORDER BY` queries against your string properties, you must specify a precision of `-1` for the corresponding paths.

There are more documents about saving RUs for your reference.

1.https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2018/04/07/is-azure-cosmos-db-really-expensive/

2.https://medium.com/@thomasweiss_io/how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-cosmos-dbs-request-units-92c68c62c938